# Django ImportError: Couldn't import Django

Tags: python, django

I have a project about django web, this project has no problem on other computers, but pycharm on my own laptop prompts for the following information

> ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate  a virtual environment?

I use PyCharm Professional and PyCharm3  My system is Windows 10. Can someone help?

Comment: So, have you configured `PYTHONPATH` ?

Comment: If you have created any venv  then you can activate it if not you have to install django. Are you sure installed django properly in your system ?

Comment: have you tried to run from command prompt? possible reasons are already written in error message. double check for it. or might be you have incorrectly configured pycharm

Comment: My computer command line runs python perfectly and can import django

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit vague as you haven't included any details about your setup/config and what steps you took to get the error, but usually these types of errors are down to a single step that has been missed during the initial installation/setup process.

I would recommend checking whether Python is properly configured and has been added to system path. Also check whether you've got Django installed with `pip freeze` (if you're in a virtual environment make sure you activate it and then run the command).

Alternatively here's a [basic Django setup guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNQxxpM1yOs) which you can run through and as well as a [PyCharm-specific Django setup guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-django-project.html).

If all else fails, you should try re-installing both Python and PyCharm and try again.

Comment: If I create a new django project with pycharm, pycharm will work perfectly, but if I open the project I copied from my computer there will be a django not found prompt, I think it is a configuration error, how can I solve

Comment: I have solved my problem, this copy of my project did not import django this package, thank you for answering everyone

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked with `deactivate` and then `source` the `venv` again.
From the outer folder:

```
$ source ./venv/bin/activate
```